# Woocommerce templates override not working for my wordpress admin user

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, overriding, admin

I have a new theme of wordpress but my templates in a woocommerce folder not working when I logged with my admin user account.

Comment: Please describe it more... with this much info it is difficult.

Comment: I used templates for override woocommerce front end but when I am logged with my admin account that templates not work, for customer users works fine.